# How do we convert a pex file to a psc file?

Tags: skyrim-modding

How do we convert a pex file to a psc file?

https://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=2909

There used to be a file here that allegedly converted pex files to psc files, but it's no longer available, so I was wondering if there was a alternative GUI program that allows you to do this. I am trying to modify a pex file in a Skyrim mod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `PapyrusAssembler.exe` to decompile the `.pex` (which is a compiled Papyrus script) into something more human-readable:

```
PapyrusAssembler.exe <name of .pex without extension> -D
```

However [the documentation notes](https://www.creationkit.com/index.php?title=Papyrus_Compiler_Reference#Disassembling_scripts_with_PapyrusAssembler.exe) that this output isn't the `.psc` file itself. You can also look for a `.pex` decompiler (or write one yourself). [The Creation Kit documentation](https://www.creationkit.com/index.php?title=Papyrus_Introduction) doesn't seem to detail the format of the `.pex` file, so unless you want to spend a lot of time reverse-engineering it you're probably better off finding a pre-written tool.

Searching the web for "Skyrim pex decompiler" yields a few results, [including a link to this tool](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/2909). These sorts of tools are usually never able to recover the *original* source code (since often, most of that information -- such as comments -- is lost when compiling). Poking around a little, it looks like they're useful for producing human-readable stuff but that stuff isn't necessarily human *friendly* and may not immediately be re-compilable as a new `.pex` without editing.

[This one](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/35307) claims to be able to produce something that is round-trip capable, even if it isn't the original file.

---

If you're doing this to recover source code to scripts you've written, and subsequently lost, it won't get you all the way there (and next time, you may want to consider a backup solution).

If you're doing this to try to figure out how scripts you didn't write function, you may have better results trying to contact the author of the script and see if they can't just explain it to you. If they're not willing to do that, they may also not be okay with your decompiling their scripts.

Comment: It creates a pexd file and not a psc file.

Comment: Right; "pexd" and "psc" are just text files; as I noted it's usually quite hard to produce original source code for something compiled, because information is lost. While doing some follow-up research I found a second tool (now linked in the answer) that claims to produce output that is round-trip capable, you might try that one.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling happens for instance via Champollion compiler, an external application added by Bethesda to Creation Kit.
You can find it [here](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/35307?tab=posts). You can also use Notepad++ and Sublime to compile or just use the version of the compiler build in the Creation Kit.

If you use the Notepad tools, it's a good idea to install the library of Papyrus for Skyrim.
[Here](https://www.creationkit.com/index.php?title=Category:Papyrus), in the official Bethesda CK wiki for Skyrim, you find a walkthrough how to use 5 different text editors for compiling scripts.